# we are losing data in elastic search cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, clustered-index, data-loss

We make a poc with ElasticSearch but while doing it, we lost data in clustered enviroment. We use ES 2.4.0.

Can anyone say what we are missing?

Our scenario is:

1. Open Elastic Server-1 and Server-2 with the configurations below,
   they are in a cluster.
2. Index document over Server-1:

   curl -XPUT '20.20.20.5:9200/ert/post/1' -d '
   {
   "user": "easlan",
   "postDate": "01-16-2015",
   "body": "Adding Data in ElasticSearch Cluster" ,
   "title": "ElasticSearch Cluster Test - 1"
   }'
3. Look for indexed docs over Server-1 or Server-2:Total number of results is 1(as expected):

   curl -XGET '20.20.20.5:9200/ert/post/_search?q=user:easlan&pretty=true'
   curl -XGET '20.20.20.6:9200/ert/post/_search?q=user:easlan&pretty=true'
4. Then close Server-1
5. Index new document over Server-2:

   curl -XPUT '20.20.20.6:9200/ert/post/2' -d '
   {
   "user": "easlan",
   "postDate": "01-16-2015",
   "body": "Adding Data in ElasticSearch Cluster" ,
   "title": "ElasticSearch Cluster Test - 2"
    }'
6. Look for indexed docs over Server-2:Total number of results is 2:

   curl -XGET '20.20.20.6:9200/ert/post/_search?q=user:easlan&pretty=true'
7. Close Server-2
8. Open Server-1
9. Look for indexed docs over Server-1:Total number of results is 1 (as expected, because server-2 is closed):

   curl -XGET '20.20.20.5:9200/ert/post/_search?q=user:easlan&pretty=true'
10. Then open Server-2 again. Look for indexed docs over Server-1 or Server-2. We expect to see total number of results as 2 but when we look, we got 1 as a result. Even we restart two of them again the result is still 1:

    curl -XGET '20.20.20.5:9200/ert/post/_search?q=user:easlan&pretty=true'
    curl -XGET '20.20.20.6:9200/ert/post/_search?q=user:easlan&pretty=true'

Our Configurations:

```
*** Server-1 ****
cluster.name: ESCluster
node.master: true
node.name: "es1"
node.data: true
network.bind_host: ["127.0.0.1","20.20.20.5"]
network.publish_host: "20.20.20.5"
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["20.20.20.5","20.20.20.6"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1

*** Server-2 ****
cluster.name: ESCluster
node.master: true
node.name: "es2"
node.data: true
network.bind_host: ["127.0.0.1","20.20.20.6"]
network.publish_host: "20.20.20.6"
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["20.20.20.5","20.20.20.6"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

Comment: Can you post response of your_server_ip:9200/_nodes/stats

Comment: Of course, but for which step ? I mean, do you want it after the scenario is completed or before the scenario, or when two server is up or in other case? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @jay please visit the link for result: [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/5jby1p6buvld5km/node_stats.json?dl=0)  this was taken after step 10.

Comment: Question is answered at https://discuss.elastic.co/t/we-are-losing-data-in-elastic-search-cluster-v2-4-0/62011 Thanks.